# Linux SMTP Server For Java Application

Tags: smtp

We currently have an e-mail processing application written in Java running on a Windows server that we are looking to migrate to a Linux server.  The current Windows server has the IIS SMTP service running.  Here is how things work right now:

1. The IIS SMTP service receives incoming e-mails and simply stores them in a folder.  Each e-mail is currently stored as an .eml file.  The IIS SMTP service performs no relaying at all.
2. The Java application runs periodically to process each e-mail message stored in the folder mentioned previously.

We're hoping we can find a Linux SMTP server that can do something similar to what the IIS SMTP service is doing on our existing Windows server for this application.   I haven't had much experience working with mail servers on Linux.  Can anyone suggest an appropriate Linux mail server for this project given the requirements discussed above?  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

`exim` (and others) can do this -- you will need to configure the MTA to deliver to a `maildir`-formatted mailbox.